# How to created Public Navbar and Protected Navbar with React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created two Navbar Public and Protected. When someone clicks on Login or Sign up the users will go to Login or Sign up page to fill in their informant.

When someone going to Login or Sign up page. Theirs no form the page is blank. If anyone has some suggestions or advice.

[Landing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eNeq.png)

[Login but it's blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HguwX.png)

**Public**

```
const Public = () => (//Created an public component Navbar

    <Router>
      <Navbar expand="lg">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/home">Kommonplaces</Navbar.Brand>

          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav pullRight className="navright">
              <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">
              <li className="RightNav">
                <Link to="/">Activities</Link>
              </li></NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">
              <li className="RightNav">
                <Link to="/">List Your Space</Link>
              </li></NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} title="Item">
              <li className="RightNav">
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}>
                    <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
                </Route>
              </li></NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">

              <li className="RightNav">
                <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}>
                  <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
                </Route>
              </li></NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </Router>

);
```

**Protected**

```
const Protected = () => (//Created an Protected component Navbar

  <Router>
    <Navbar expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/home">Kommonplaces</Navbar.Brand>

        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav pullRight className="navright">
            <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">
            <li className="RightNav">
              <Link to="/">Become a Planner</Link>
            </li></NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">
            <li className="RightNav">
              <Link to="/">Saved</Link>
            </li></NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} title="Item">
            <li className="RightNav">
              <Link to="/">Events</Link>
            </li></NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">
            <li className="RightNav">
              <Link to="/">Help</Link>
            </li></NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
</Router>
);
```

**App**

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
              <div>
                <Route path="/" component={Public} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Protected} />
                <Switch> 
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/login" component={Protected} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

PrivateRounte.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (

  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: Post Your private route HOC code.

Comment: @adel I have just posted mu private route HOC code. Sorry about that I forgot.

Comment: are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: So,  I just checked their no error in the console

Comment: why you using router and route inside Public! tell me what are you trying to achieve so maybe i can give you a solution.

Comment: I'm trying to create a login and signup from but I have already made a server with Node.js and Express.JS, MongoDB. Now trying to create a navbar that changes when someone login is similar to Airbnb --> https://gyazo.com/8225f2fe7ae78e4f7ff939008c528326

Comment: Please, explain with detail have a hard time comprehending things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first to render navbar u can use condition depending on auth like this:

```
const render_user = () => {
if (auth) {
  return (
    <NavItem eventKey={1} title="Item">
      Welcome User
    </NavItem>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} title="Item">
        <li className="RightNav">
          <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
        </li>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">
        <li className="RightNav">
          <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
        </li>
      </NavItem>
    </>
  );
}
};
```

here if user isn't `logged in` will show default buttons and if is `logged in` will show user

second if you don't want to show `navbar` on `login` page and `register` page you can structure your Routes like this:

```
   const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route component={DefaultLayout} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const DefaultLayout = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <Navigationbar />
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
  </div>
);
```

in your `DefaultLayout` we are rendering `Navigationbar` wich will not show in your `login` page and `register` page

check full code here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sunset-i9y69)

i used redux hooks not normal connect function!

hope this what you are looking for.

Comment: How are you Identifying two names with have given. you error message on already been declared

Comment: @bpdg i don't get what are you trying to ask. please explain more!

Comment: You have two components called DefaultLayout but when every I tried to add two different components gives me error message like here --> https://gyazo.com/e869bdac43a4892155769b93302a4e30?token=db0ef69716bc776cc635ab030919ae81

Comment: @bpdg this error is not related to my code. you just have 2 landing component maybe you are import a component called Landing you need to give other name!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic here and use the `<PrivateRoute />` component from `react-router-dom`

This [article](https://medium.com/@tomlarge/private-routes-with-react-router-dom-28e9f40c7146) explains the steps to do it

Comment: Are you talking about the file that ready-created call PrivateRoute.js or it inside of the Navbar.js file?